# React component - onClick and nothing happens, why is that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created the following class. Everything seems correct according to documentation and examples, but the onClick event doesn't happen. Why is that?

```
import React from 'react'
import Champion from './Champion'


class Champions extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            champions: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var req1 = new Request('http://localhost:8080/api/champions')
        fetch(req1, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                var championsArr = []
                for (const champ of data) {
                    championsArr.push(champ)
                }
                this.setState({ champions: championsArr })
            })
    }

    handleClick(itemId) {
        console.log(itemId)
    }


    render() {
        const items = this.state.champions.map(item => <Champion onClick={() => this.handleClick.bind(this, item.id)} key={item.id} id={item.id} championName={item.name} />)

        return (
            <div className="tab-pane fade show active all-objects" id="pills-champions" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-champions-tab">
                { items }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Champions
```

I also tried `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item.id)}` but it does nothing as well.

Edit: Here is the code for the Champion component (removed the class definition and exports):

```
    render() {
        return (
            <button className="card" style={{ width: "8rem" }}>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/126/126" className="card-img-top" alt=""></img>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-text">id: {this.props.id}. name: {this.props.championName}</p>
                </div>
            </button>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of `Champion` component as well to have some understanding of how you trigger on click actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to double bind the function. You can either put it inside a scoped arrow function, or you can call `.bind` on it.

Choose either one of the following

```js
const items = this.state.champions.map(item => <Champion onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)} key={item.id} id={item.id} championName={item.name} />)
```

```js
const items = this.state.champions.map(item => <Champion onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item.id)} key={item.id} id={item.id} championName={item.name} />)
```

You could also just use the built-in event

```js
handleClick(event) {
  debugger
}
```

Sadly you don't want to use a console.log statement here because the event will expire and React will clean it up, losing you access to the memory. With a debugger statement, you can at least inspect the memory and explore, but it should show that by using the built-in event, you should still be able to access the data you've scoped to the even target. Just don't forget to bind it with either an arrow function(binds to the scope of creation) or by calling `.bind()`

Next, we need to find your render on your Champion component and actually bind the function to the DOM itself an we'll place it right on the button.

```js
<button className="card" style={{ width: "8rem" }} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
```

Remember that with a custom component, for an `onClick` to propagate to the DOM to be bound, you must attach it to something that eventually renders to the DOM. Custom components don't do that automatically as they're expecting you to link that logic, and rightfully so. `onClick` on a custom class is just a variable.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens.

Comment: Then we're going to need to see your `Champion` component

Comment: updated with a fix for the champion component. Have fun